# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/11/2014"

Tags: java, eclipse, date

I am trying to get the difference betweek to dates

```
String start_date, end_date;
    System.out.println("Date Format: MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss (24-hour format)");
    System.out.print("Start Date and Time: ");
    start_date = cin.next();
    System.out.print("End Date and Time: ");
    end_date = cin2.next();
    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
    try
    {
        date1 = date_format.parse(start_date);
        date2 = date_format.parse(end_date);long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
    System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
    System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
    System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

I keep on getting this error

```
Date Format: MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss (24-hour format)
Start Date and Time: 11/11/2014 11:11:11
End Date and Time: 11/21/2014 11:11:11
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/11/2014"
```

please help me

Comment: Why are you lying about your date format?

Comment: well you need to use the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` which is not the same as  `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Use cin.nextLine() it should work fine!

Comment: Not what you asked, but this way of doing things will give you an error of one hour if only one of your start date and your end date falls during daylight savings time.  If you're doing this as a learning exercise, then don't worry too much.  But don't use the code that you've written here in any kind of production application.

Answer (score 5):

Notice your output

```
Start Date and Time: 11/11/2014 11:11:11
...
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/11/2014"
```

You entered

```
11/11/2014 11:11:11
```

but only tried to parse

```
11/11/2014
```

`Scanner#next()` used here

```
start_date = cin.next();
```

tokenizes on whitespace (by default). Use `Scanner#nextLine()` to get the full line.